# Need help about sound processing

Tags: android, audio, mp3, processing, sampling

How to get the sample data from stereo sound file (.mp3) and push them into the buffer?
Is there any specific library with that function?
Sorry if the question is really noob, I'm very new to audio programming.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The only way you can play an MP3 file via direct Android API is MediaPlayer which is heavyweight, slow and presents only high-level API. If you need to mix or modify audio streams or manage them with low latency, you are on your own."*

(Via: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/ )

So that is unfortunate.  JLayer is free and written in Java, so you can use that:

http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html

Whether it's going to be fast enough depends on how much analysis you want to do, and what kind of processor is in the phone, what other apps are running.  All the usual things.

You can write native code and use C/C++ libraries if you have something CPU intensive, which will give you a better chance at doing real-time analysis:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

Some ARM processors have vector instructions and the like you could exploit if they're available, which can give a speed boost:

http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/neon.php

If what you're doing can't be pure real-time, you might consider doing full or partial pre-processing.  Then cache the analysis info so the user only has to wait the first time...or give them the option to let your app analyze all the files overnight or somesuch.

Comment: So that means it's not possible to create an application in Android which can load music files in the phone (which mostly will be in mp3 format) and analyze them in the run-time smoothly?
I have created a mechanism to browse all music files in the phone and play the music based on user selection using MediaPlayer. So now, I want to analyze the music in the run-time or maybe provide certain time for the system to analyze the music before being played.

Comment: One more question, I'm going to apply simple beat detection algorithm. It's basically getting the samples from the audio, calculate stuffs, and determine whether there is beat or not. Do you think it requires heavy processing? I've found a library specifically for beat detection http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/manual-beatdetect/, although it's written in Java but it seems not created for Eclipse because it is created for Processing (it requires PApplet, which is Processing Applet). The way it is written looks simple enough so I assumed that beat detection algorithm is not that heavy

Comment: You're just going to have to profile on the devices you're interested in to see if you can get the effect you want with a certain technical stack.  Bad beat detection is cheap, and impressive beat detection is an AI task.  I'm not sure what kind of chipset Snowball(tm) is running, but he does a good job, though still rather subjective whether one has found the "real" beat :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xxcoy58yElo

Comment: If you program in C++ I would advise to not be scared of the NDK, it's not that hard to set up.  By eschewing Java and writing more native code, you'll also make your app easier to port to iPhone if you ever get the inclination...not that I care for iPhone/Apple.